# Getting the real width of a text in pixels

Tags: kineticjs

How can I acheive the subject goal in KineticJS? If I use either `.getWidth()` or `.getTextWidth()` methods of the `Text` object, the given amount is the sum of widths of all letters. It does not count for the space between letters. So, I cannot get the exact width of a displayed Text. I have seen there is a solution involving some screen metrics class, but maybe there is a simpler one?

Comment: Can't you fetch it for example with jQuery with `$('<span />').text('machin chouette').width()` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do what you need, but...

**This function will get the width of text in pixels using canvas**

```
function getTextWidth(font,text){
    var canvas=document.createElement(“canvas”);
    var ctx=canvas.getContext(“2d”);
    ctx.font=font;    // for example “14pt Verdana”;
    var measure=ctx.measureText(text);
    return(measure.width);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sadly it gives the same result as the `.getTextWidth()` method of a `Text` instance. Something close to true I get if I do `measure.width + text.length` instead of simply `measure.width`, but still even this is somewhat +/-1 pixel innacurate here and there. My font is Consolas 14 and I am trying to device cursor positioning in the text element...... sadly, the precision of calculations leaves wishing for better... maybe you have some more ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can get pixel-perfect at a cost of performance. Draw your text on a canvas and then measure at which X coordinate the text starts and stops using context.getImageData().   Of course, you must weigh the cost of "perfect" versus "practical" for yourself.

Comment: heh, you mean using the scanline technique? :D. oh this 21st century, gimme a break.. :D, ok, I guess this is the only way, so I try soon and when it works, this is the answer then..

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply append a hidden element to the body and check his generated width ?

With jQuery:

```javascript
element = $('<span />').addClass('hide').text('some dummy text');
element.appendTo('body');
console.log(element.width());
```

Not sure I have understood the question well, and not sure it's applicable to canvas elements.

Comment: Afaik this is for a different approach. It is possible to work with DOM elements on canvas, but here I am using only canvas-drawn ones... so this method won't work for purely drawn elements. There must be either some KineticJS way or canvas per-pixel way...